# Equality of a floating point variable initialised to zero in C

Tags: c, floating-point

I understand that equality operation should not be performed on floating point numbers due to the way the value is stored, and instead a threshold comparison should be performed. But is it safe to use equality when the value is set to a constant value, say 0?

```
void test() {
   double max = 0.0;

   do {
       if (condition) {
           if (max != 0.0) { // Is this safe
               // myval is always a large positive number
               max = min(myval, max);
           } else {
               max = myval;
           }
       }
   } while (my_condition);

   return myval;
}
```

I can see several similar questions on StackOverflow. But my question is specific to a variable assigned the constant zero (not the result of an operation).

Comment: Suppose the values of myval were successively 2.0,0.0,3.0. Then as I see it after processing these the value of of min would be successively 2.0, 0.0, 3.0.

Comment: What is the value of `max` supposed to represent?  It is certainly not the maximum value seen with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0.0` has an exact representation in [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), so if two variables are set to `0.0` their comparison should always yield true. But if in your code `max` is really always `0.0`, you might as well remove the if block because it would never execute.

Comment: Thanks. There are other parts which can modify max, which I did not include for ease of reading.

Comment: @JoyceBabu The point is that it isn't clear from your question whether it would be safe to make the comparison, because we don't know how those other parts modify `max`.

Comment: I have updated the code for better clarity. `max` is zero only when it is in its initialised state, else it is always a large positive number. So, the equality will work for 0 and only zero (no other constants). Is that correct?

Comment: @JoyceBabu The argument applies to `0.` as well as any other number that is exactly representable in IEEE-754.

Comment: @JoyceBabu But what happens if you do some arithmetic on `max` in runtime, and then afterwards it sometimes gets set to exactly zero and sometimes it gets set to something which is very close to zero? I think your program would turn unreliable still, even though as long as the variable remains untouched, it is guaranteed to be exactly zero.

Comment: "so if two variables are set to 0.0 their comparison should always yield true." is only half of the issue.  If one variable is set to 0.0 and another set to not arithmetic 0.0, is the comparison always false? With  IEEE-754, and ignoring NAN, there is no concern.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using IEEE-754 binary formats, yes it is safe as `0.0` can be represented exactly in IEEE-754. There is exactly one representation for `+0` in binary formats (and one for `-0` and note also that`+0 = -0`).